# Disable Struts converting HTML tags into entities

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

Hi I'm using Struts 1.2 and I installed TinyMCE. The problem is that struts is converting all HTML tags into entities. How do I disable or configure this to allow only selected tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the filter parameter ([taglib](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#bean:write)).

```
<bean:write name="someField" filter="false"/>
```

Comment: Can I choose which tags to filter?

Comment: Do you mean override the default behaviour of the tag rather than specify filter on each tag? If so, I think you'd have to hack around with the struts jars.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean can I specify what HTML tags to filter and what not to filter?

Comment: The filtering doesn't look at or understand HTML tags, it just replaces a few characters, see http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/struts/taglib/TagUtils.java.html#x616

If you want to do this the easiest way is probably to create a special getter and put the logic in there.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I was looking for this but in Struts 2, and this helped, it's similar:

```
<s:property value="variable" escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is a correct response for struts 2. At least on the later versions

escape property does not exist.

There are escapes for html, csv , javascript and xml which needs to be explicitly mentioned.
example for html, it has to be escapeHtml

```
<s:property value="%{somefield}" escapeHtml="false"/>
```