# Preserving white space in an HTML select option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of html text boxes that take input and when the user clicks an 'add' button uses javascript to take the text input and format a string that is put in an HTML select box. The first of these boxes is supposed to contain a 2 character number but can also accept a blank. The formatted strings would look like this:

```
01-ABC-O
02-DEF-I
```

However I need a way to display the blank numbers that lines up with the other elements

```
 -GHI-O
```

This type of entry will show up fine when the javascript adds the option, but when the page is reloaded and the select is repopulated with the values (I'm using Java, jsp, and struts 1.1 if that helps) it gets the same values(spaces preserved) but the whitespace is no longer shown in the select control (I've looked at the page source, and it looks identical to when the javascript adds the option). I have tried substituting the spaces for `&nbsp;` but this just prints the string "&nbsp" instead of the space. I've also tried using "pre" html blocks and the css white-space property and neither have worked.

Let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: Can you provide a small code sample that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: These select boxes that you are referring to. Are they using the option attribute or the value between the opening and closing option element? The space is not preserved if you are relying on the space between the element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to replace the spaces with `&nbsp;` and it should work - note the closing semi-colon (which is missing from your example in the question)! When you do it through Javascript, most (all?) browsers will automatically render the spaces, but when the spaces are there when the page is loaded all (sometimes all but one) of them will be ignored.

You should also apply a `font-family:` CSS attribute to the select that specifies mono-spaced font(s) in order to ensure everything lines up properly.

Comment: I am using a mono-spaced font, and sorry about the confusion with the `&nbsp;` I just didn't know how to mark it as code so that the comment box wouldn't render it as HTML, I am actually using that as `&nbsp;`

Comment: Ok, no worries - which browsers have you tested this in? Because this works for me in Chrome and IE8 - I just did a quick sanity check and it definitely does...

Comment: Please will you just double check your HTML source, and make sure that you haven't accidentally double-escaped it? I.e. make sure it outputs `&nbsp;` and not `&amp;nbsp;`?

Comment: Chrome and IE7, I have tried the following option format(added through javascript): `&nbsp;&nbsp;-GHI-O` and it prints that exact string rather than making those spaces.

Comment: ...and if you add it through Javascript using literal spaces, what happens? They just get eaten?

Comment: No, it shows the spaces until I get a refresh or postback, then the values are the same as before, but spaces are "eaten"

Comment: looks like this `<select name="permittedSelect" size="4" id="permittedSelect" style="width:120; white-space:pre-wrap;">
<option value="  -ATL-B">  -ATL-B</option>
<option value="  -MCI-B">  -MCI-B</option>
</select>
` either way but before refresh/postback there is spaces, after: no spaces

Comment: I though so, and what I was getting at (although reading back over my answer, not very clearly) is that when you *re-generate* the page (i.e. at the server side) you should use `&nbsp;`, but from Javascript you should use a literal space. Javascript will automatically convert strings to HTML entities when it modifies the DOM (actually it doesn't really, but that is the effect it has) whereas when the browser receives a page from the server (refresh/postback etc) HTML entities must be explicit.

Comment: So in other words you should do a find/replace on the spaces at the server side, but you don't need to worry about this in your JS.

Comment: See this fiddle for an example of what you want to populate the select from the server: http://fiddle.jshell.net/NMXfe/

Comment: Okay, when I populate it from the server with `&nbsp;&nbsp;` it substitutes the `&` with `&amp;` how do I make sure it uses the correct string?

Comment: How exactly are you ouputing from the server? Somewhere it is being passed through a procedure that automatically escapes HTML special characters, and you need to remove this. If you do this you will need to ensure you manually escape all characters that need to be escaped - literal ampersands need to be `$amp;`, `<` needs to be `&lt;` etc etc...

Comment: The project is using jsp and struts 1.1, so I am merely setting the java variable that corresponds to the select control to a String ArrayList. So I should set the Strings to "&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;-ABC-O"?

Comment: Nope, I suspect that would result in `&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;amp;nbsp;-ABC-O`. Hang on, let me read some docs (I am a PHP developer by default so I don't know JSP stuff off the top of my head)

Comment: Yes, I tried it and that is what happened, thank for helping.

Comment: I can't work this out, it is completely different to the way I write/script HTML (in PHP you just `echo` it - sort of like `System.out.writeln` in Java). It does seem to be a problem some people have - maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716922) will help point you in the right direction?

Comment: Wow! That works, using filter="false" prevents the entity filtering, great, Thank You!!!

Answer (score 4):

When creating the select option with javascript, to preserve white-space, use "\xa0" - it is a NO-BREAK SPACE char.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pre css style on the area that you are outputting the value to.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #element {
         white-space: pre;
    }
</style>

<div id="element">
    stuff goes here
</div>
```

This will preserve all whitespace in the div element (other element types will also work) and then you don't need to worry about using the non breaking space.

Comment: When I referred to trying the css white-space property in my initial post, this is what I meant, I tried inline and as a class.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to add it via scripting, you need to use Escape Codes for Space "% A0" which you then decode with unescape ()

```
logTypeList[i] = new Option(unescape("  kent   Agent".replace(/ /g, "%A0")), "theValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
logTypeList[i] = new Option(unescape("  kent   Agent".replace(/ /g, "%A0")), "theValue");
```

Since unescape is deprecated, you may want to use decodeURI:

```
logTypeList[i] = new Option(decodeURI("  kent   Agent".replace(/ /g, "%C2%A0")), "theValue");
```

More info at http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathsymbols.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unicode Character 'SPACE' (U+0020) instead of `&nbsp;`("\u0020")